# CentOS/Kernel v3.18/Thunderbolt2

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

I just got a new SuperMicro box with a AOC-TBT-DSL5320 Thunderbolt2 card pre-installed. I installed CentOS 6.5,ran yum update, and then, because to my understanding at least, thunderbolt support was added in kernel 3.10, I went ahead and updated to kernel 3.18 from ELRepo. This all appeared to work fine, and my system came back up running kernel 3.18 as expected, but when I plugged in a thunderbolt hard drive there was no indication that CentOS recognized the drive - even after a re-boot. Am I missing something, such as needing to install a special driver for this thunderbolt card, or the drive being identified differently than sd? Or does Linux/CentOS simply not support Thunderbolt2? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any relevant output in `dmesg`?

Comment: @HalosGhost Not that I've been able to pick out of all the noise there, no. If it is seeing the thunderbolt card/drive, it's identifying it in a way I don't recognize. Which would be easy enough :-)